# How to Integrate swagger UI with Apache wicket web application and its rest apis

Tags: swagger, wicket

I have an apache wicket web application. In that, I want to integrate swagger UI. Is there any integration with the apache wicket. If anyone works on apache wicket and if you go through with swagger UI then please share your thoughts.
         In my case all the api manage through the mountResource(name, staticResourceRefernce) method.
I am trying to add a Docket object in WebMarkupContainer.

```
public class SwaggerUiPage extends WebPage {
public static final SwaggerUiPageResource PAGE_RESOURCE    = new SwaggerUiPageResource();

private IModel<Docket> model;

@Override
protected void onInitialize() {
    super.onInitialize();
    model.setObject(postsApi());
    add(new WebMarkupContainer("swagger",model));
}

@Bean
public Docket postsApi() {
    Docket docket = new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).groupName("public-api")
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.app"))
            .paths(PathSelectors.ant("/api/*"))
            .build();
    return docket;
}
```

}

[This is the swagger-ui.html page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tzkwm.png)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

back in 2017 I've tried to provide an integration with [rest-annotations](https://github.com/bitstorm/core/commits/swagger-integration) module and Swagger. I never had the chance to finish this work so I just came to a partial implementation using a SwaggerResource to expose API information and a SwaggerUtils class to extract rest endpoints information. If you want you can take a look at the code here:
https://github.com/bitstorm/core/commits/swagger-integration